# failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException:

Tags: asp.net, rest, web-services, date, jakarta-ee

Hello i'm trying to consume rest web service from jee application to asp.net 
when i copy the url it work perfectly but when i excute it from the app the url changes specifically the dates .

Example of the erorr :

> 22:03:32,629 WARN  [org.jboss.resteasy.core.ExceptionHandler] (default
>   task-69) failed to execute: javax.ws.rs.NotFoundException: Could not
>   find resource for full path:
>   http://localhost:18080/PiDev-web/rest/absence/creates/aaaqwqwq/07/11/2018%2000:00:00/07/11/2018%2000:00:00

[JEE app]

here's my service :

```
@Override
    public void createAbsence(Absence e) {
        EmployeService ee =new EmployeService();
        ConnectedUser emp = em.find(ConnectedUser.class, 1); 

        System.out.println("Service Done 0 !!!");
        e.setIdEmploye(emp.getId());
        e.setLogin(emp.getLogin());
        e.setJustifie(false);

        //e.setEmploye(UserConnected);
        em.persist(e);
        System.out.println("Service Done !!!");

    }
```

and myBean:

```
@POST
    @Path("/creates/{cause}/{dd}/{df}") 
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response serviceCreates(@PathParam(value = "cause") String cause,@PathParam(value = "dd") String dd,@PathParam(value = "df") String df) {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Date dated=new Date();

        Date datef=new Date();


                    try {

                        dated = dateFormat.parse(dd);
                        datef = dateFormat.parse(df);

                        System.out.println(dated);



                    } catch (ParseException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();

                    }

        return Response.status(Status.ACCEPTED).entity(absenceService.createAbsence(new Absence(cause,dated,datef))).build();

    }
```

[Asp.Net app]
Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(absence abs)
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient Client = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
            Console.WriteLine(abs.dateDebut);
            Client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:18080/PiDev-web/rest/absence/");
            Client.PostAsJsonAsync<absence>("creates/" + abs.cause + "/" + abs.dateDebut + "/" + abs.dateFin, abs);
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```

and my view :

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/backLayout.cshtml";
}

@model ProjectWeb.Models.absence


    @using (Html.BeginForm())
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Add Absence</h4>
            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.cause, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.cause, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.cause, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dateDebut, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dateDebut, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dateDebut, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.dateFin, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">

                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.dateFin, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.dateFin, "", new { @class = "t-danger" })
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
```

i'm not familiar with date formats so if you are familiar please help me

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your url that you use slash to separate year, month and day. Actually url use slash to separate part of path, so you have to not use slash except separate element of path. 
For sending date it's better to use ISO format. Long story short you write date from biggest to lowest values and separate them using dash (year-month-dayThour:minutes:seconds) example

```
date time 2018-11-07T22:30:33
only date 2018-11-07
```

Rewrite your resource like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/creates/{cause}/{dd}/{df}") 
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response serviceCreates(@PathParam(value = "cause") String cause,@PathParam(value = "dd") LocalDate dd,@PathParam(value = "df") LocalDate df) {
    return Response.status(Status.ACCEPTED).entity(absenceService.createAbsence(new Absence(cause,dd,df))).build();

}
```

and try to invoke:

> http://localhost:18080/PiDev-web/rest/absence/creates/aaaqwqwq/2018-11-07/2018-11-07

Comment: Actually i use - for dates when try it on post man it work ls but when i use it through an application it changes to / and i don’t know how

Comment: Then you can find answer here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings

Comment: Thank you very much for your time :)